# Techniques for integrating this function?

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I'm working my way through a textbook on probability in which the following integral appears:

$$F(y)=\int_1^\infty y^{n-1}\lambda^ne^{-\lambda y}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}dy-\int_1^\infty y^{n-2}\lambda^{n-1}e^{-\lambda y}\frac{1}{(n-2)!}dy~~~~　　(1)$$

The author performs the integration in a single step:

$$F(y)=\left[-\frac{1}{\lambda}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}(y^{n-1}\lambda^ne^{-\lambda y})\right]_1^\infty~~~~　　(2)$$

I just can't follow how the author jumps from (1) to (2). Is there some sort of integration technique I should know about?

Comment: Have you tried considering gamma distribution?

Comment: Thanks for the edits! And no, I haven't learned about gamma distribution yet, so I don't know how it applies to this problem. From what I understand the author is just performing an integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dy} \left(-\frac{y^{n-1} \lambda^n e^{-\lambda y}}{\lambda\left(n-1\right)!} \right) &=  - \left(-\lambda\right)\frac{y^{n-1} \lambda^n e^{-\lambda y}}{\lambda\left(n-1\right)!} -\left(n-1\right)\frac{y^{n-2} \lambda^n e^{-\lambda y}}{\lambda\left(n-1\right)!} \\
&=  \frac{y^{n-1} \lambda^{n} e^{-\lambda y}}{\left(n-1\right)!} -\frac{y^{n-2} \lambda^{n-1} e^{-\lambda y}}{\left(n-2\right)!},
\end{align}
$$
so
$$
\int_a^b dy\left[\frac{y^{n-1} \lambda^{n} e^{-\lambda y}}{\left(n-1\right)!} -\frac{y^{n-2} \lambda^{n-1} e^{-\lambda y}}{\left(n-2\right)!}\right] = \left[-\frac{y^{n-1} \lambda^n e^{-\lambda y}}{\lambda\left(n-1\right)!} \right]_a^b.
$$

Comment: Amazing--so it's integration by parts, it just took some pattern matching. Thanks so much!